# Remove union large vectors in c++ efficiently?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to union a million vectors for doing so I am using the following program. Each of the vectors contain a billion elements. The result of the union should not contain any duplicates.

```
set<unsigned> myfunc()
{
    vector<vector<unsigned> > vec(1000000); 
    set<unsigned> result;
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
       result.insert(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end()); //vec[i] contains a billion elements

    return result;
}
```

Is there some way by which I may union the two large vectors effectively? As the above code seems to be running for more than 2 hours. I am running the code on a machine with 128 GB RAM

Comment: `vector<unsigned> vec(1000000);` -- This is a single vector of `unsigned` values, not multiple vectors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks sorry for the typo.

Comment: _"... union a million vectors ... Each of the vectors contain a billion elements ..."_ - do the maths - how much memory does this need? Smells of an XY problem.

Comment: Your code does not show how your vectors are filled with data.

Comment: You're asking about removing elements and in your code is insertion. `remove_if` has O(n), double you'll do better.

Comment: Incoming `std::bad_alloc`.... as @RichardCritten mentioned you are going to run out of memory way before you can allocate these vectors

Comment: @JannatArora -- What is the reason for a million vectors with billions of integers?  Sounds like you're trying to implement a "solution" for something that works well for small amounts of values, but is not practical for millions or billions of values.

Comment: If you want to end up with a `set<>`, you can, theoretically, insert values into the set one-by-one instead of having to have vectors each holding a billion elements *at the same time*.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious approach is to use `std::set_union()` with `std::sort()`ed `std::vector<unsigned>`s:

```
std::vector<unsigned> myfunc()
{
    vector<vector<unsigned> > vec(1000000);
    std::vector<unsigned> result, tmp;
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        std::sort(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end())
        std::set_union(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end(),
                       result.begin(), result.end(),
                       std::back_inserter(tmp));
        swap(tmp, result);
        tmp.clear();
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but just out of curosity why is std::set_union faster than set insertion?

Comment: It doesn't walk a data structure randomly distributed in memory with an unpredictable access pattern. instead, it does highly structured memory accesses in contiguous memory. I haven't measured the effects of both implementation but I'm pretty sure that using `std::set_union()` is substantially faster (although not theoretical asymptotic complexity is the same).